# Unexpected interface name - Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

I am working on an application that retrieves photos from iOS photo library. When the photo is selected, I want to target a .xib to show an interface where the selected photo can be edited.

However the build is failing due to this error:

> "Unexpected interface name 'imageEditorView': expected expression"

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:imageEditorView: animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

I have all the externals imported correctly in the .h files for both controllers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to do with this code? when application launching what you are dismissing??

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: self.parentViewController? In the app delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- `imageEditorView` is the name of a class.  That will not work as a message argument.  You need to pass a reference to an object.
- You have an extra colon after `imageEditorView`, before `animated`.  You need to remove it.
- Sending `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` to `self` inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` doesn't make any sense.  Either you are defining this method in your application delegate, which doesn't understand the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` message, or you are defining it in a view controller, in which case `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will not be called (unless you write code to explicitly call it, which would also be very unusual).

Based on all these errors, I suspect that you do not really know much Objective-C or iOS programming at all.  You need to work through some tutorials to learn the basics, because these are very basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self.parentViewController presentViewController:imageEditorView: animated:YES completion:nil];
        // in your code problem must be here

        }];
    }
imageEditorView *svc = [[imageEditorView alloc]initWithNibName:@"imageEditorView"  bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:imageEditorView: animated:YES completion:nil];
----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You should use like this

```
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:imageEditorView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The colon would not cause the error he quoted.  The error he quoted happened because `imageEditorView` is a class name, not a variable name.  If he changes it to a variable name, then he will get the error “Use of undeclared identifier 'animated'” (because of the colon).